# DataSnap Rest server under router

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I developed DataSnap Rest server in Delphi. It is distributed in all our customers. Basically it is small desktop application that server data from customers to our web server. 
Now, customers need to forward the ports of router, open ports in firewall, etc. and it is really hard for most of them.

Which methods could I use for avoiding to change the network configuration?

I am studying polling, WebSockets, ... but I am really confused about what would be a good solution. The purpose is to facilitate the installation of our application to the end user.

Comment: Am I reading this right. You want to put the server on your end user's machine? Which means that the end user's machine has to listen and allow incoming connections. That sounds like a recipe for serious security flaws. Which is why you are battling to get it configured. In any corporate environment this would be flatly denied.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I need to install an app in each customer. This app has to listen incoming connections from our server. However I am not clear why you say that it would be denied. Skype, DropBox, etc. basically do the same, they install an app and listen incoming connections.

Comment: @DabielKabuto TCP connections are bidirectional - Clients can open a connection to a central server and then continuously listen for incoming data packets instead of opening their own listening TCP port. This is more firewall-friendly than how Skype and DropBox work.

Comment: @Dabiel Nobody is going to open up ports like that. This is 2015!

Comment: There are very real security issues here. Your lack of appreciation of them makes you dangerous to anybody who uses your software. You really need to step back and spend some time learning networking basics.

Comment: As a common rule: The client connects to the server. And the internal server is a client from the external one.

Comment: In any case, then, how my server can initiate the communication with the customer PCs? Basically, my server needs periodically to collect data from customers. Data collection is generated by an external event from mobile devices, so customer PC never knows when it will be contacted.

Comment: The clients, who have the data to be collected, should periodically send data to your server. You have to run the server and put clients on the customer machines. Why do you believe that you should be the exception to the rule?

Comment: I try to understand what you suggest, sorry if I look I should be the exception. Your proposal does not fit in my scenario. Clients cannot send data to my server if they do not have a specific request. Clients have millions of records in a database, and only some of them are required under demand by my server. Client cannot know when and which records will be required. My first attempt was exposing the customer app as a server, It seems more natural since they "serve" data and they cannot initiate the connection. You advised me that it was dangerous, so I am trying to find another way.